# java executeUpdate for a pl-sql always returns 1 even if the row doesn't exist

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I have the following java code where the output of executeUpdate() is being captured in a int and the value is always 1. For the input values there are no rows in DB but it still returns 1. Why? Am I missing something?

```
    /*******************Java code *************/


    /**** Code to get connection above ***/
    CallableStatement oraCallStmt   = null;

    try {
        oraCallStmt =   connection.prepareCall(
                "{ call XXXXX.UPDATEMEMBERNUMBER(?,?)}"
            );
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return ;
    }
        try {
            //Reading a comma delimited file to get two column values
            //One into the where clause and one into the update clause
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] ar = str.split(",");

                oraCallStmt.setString(1,ar[0].trim());
                oraCallStmt.setString(2,ar[1].trim());

                int output = oraCallStmt.executeUpdate();

                //The output returns 1 always even if the row doesn't exist
                System.out.println(str +'-'+output);

                //Writing the result to another file
                bw.write(str +'-'+output);
                bw.newLine() ;
                bw.flush();
            }
            bw.close();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    /************pl-sql package*******************/

    PROCEDURE UpdateMemberNumber(CUSTID_INP IN VARCHAR,
                         MEM_NUM_INP IN VARCHAR) IS
    BEGIN
       UPDATE GENESIS.CUSTOMER
       SET MEMBER_NUMBER = MEM_NUM_INP
       WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTID_INP ;

    END UpdateMemberNumber ;
```

Comment: This is a good question. But I think that executeUpdate() returns number of affected rows only for DML statements. Procedures are more complex. Imagine that such procedure may call several other procedures that could update or delete rows as well. What would executeUpdate() return in such case? So I think that for procedures it just returns a constant.

Comment: My requirement is to use pl-sql procedures to do the update. Is there any other way of knowing if the update failed for a particular row?

Comment: You  can detect such situation in plsql code and return in out parameter

Comment: try getUpdateCount() method?  per http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-by-jdbc-java-class/169, executeUpdate is preferred when storedProc does not return result. I am not sure of the validity of this article. It mentios about excuteQuery and execute methods. You may try them.

Comment: Take a look at my blog, there is a procedure with out parameter. You can use it as template. http://www.literak.cz/2013/08/working-with-complex-database-types-in-weblogic/